# How to access files (documents, drives..) in i3wm?

Tags: i3-wm

I am new to i3wm, so would like to know which command to use to access the files on my system.

Answer (score 10):

What "Ravexina" suggested is correct, although I would suggest that after `Mod` + `D`, i.e from `dmenu` try using `nautilus --no-desktop`. This will get rid of that pesky desktop that opens up every time you open `nautilus`.

Answer (score 9):

Press <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to make "dmenu" appear, then type in `nautilus` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>, a new window will came up and you will have access to your files.

[image: dmenu]

Depend on your configuration <kbd>Meta</kbd> could be <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>SUPER</kbd> (Win) keys.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on which file manager is there on your system. All answers assumed it to be "nautilius" without the user explicitly specifying his system specifications (as different flavours of ubuntu comes with different file managers like pcmanfm in LUbuntu etc).

So I would suggest you first get the knowledge of the file manager on your system and proceed as follows :-

Just go to the terminal by pressing <kbd>Mod</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination (this will open up a new terminal) and type the command for your respective file manager program.

or you could just simply open "dmenu" by pressing <kbd>Mod</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and enter the command there.